# How to create a jupyter-lab extension that interacts with a running kernel

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to create an extension for jupyter-lab that interacts with a running ipython kernel, running either in a console or a notebook.

As a minimal example I am trying to get two "hello world" type programs. The first should print a message to stdout of the running kernel that is input in the extension. The second should log a message to the console of the extension that is input in the running ipython kernel.

To understand jupyter-lab extension I started with the [astronomy picture of the day](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/extension_tutorial.html)! tutorial. Although this covers the basics of  extensions this does not address interacting with a running kernel.

From ["really confused with jupyter notebook lab extensions and ipywidgets"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47826117/really-confused-with-jupyter-notebook-lab-extensions-and-ipywidgets/47834304#47834304)! it seems I should be looking at the `Comms` module however this is documentation for `Jupyter-notebook` and not for `Jupyter-lab`. As far as I understand, `Jupyter-lab` is sufficiently different under the hood that this should not work.

Could someone explain to me how to create an extension that interacts with a running kernel and what the appropriate documentation/tutorial is to look at if it exists?